# element is not defined Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, html, woocommerce

I have this Uncaught ReferenceError **element is not defined** which do not understand.My problem is **this script is working** but cause of this error my **other scripts  not working properly**

can anyone give me reason for why I got **element is not defined** error?

In my woocommerce main.js file (jQuery = $ )

```
jQuery("body").delegate(".checkout", "click",function(e){
 jQuery('label').each(function(){
 var $getElement= jQuery(this).attr("for")
   if($getElement== "billing_state" ){
     var html = element.html();
     element.html(html + "<abbr class=\"required\">*</abbr>");
   }
 });
});
```

I got a error in this line **var html = element.html();**

[image]

[image]

Comment: where you defined element ??Before accessing element have a check on it.

Comment: where you defined element ?

Comment: @ OlegNurutdinov I'll didn't define it only use like this, **element.html();**

Comment: @Suresh  when I try to define element then I get " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined "

Comment: How are defining the element. Can you share that code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be :

```
var html = $getElement.html();
```

instead of:

```
var html = element.html();
```

Comment: If I use change then I get  " Uncaught TypeError: e.html is not a function " Nothing change.Script is working fine,but got this error

Comment: Can you send me complete JS file? may be we are missing something here.

Comment: @Rika `e` - is your event defined on `click()`. As I see in your code, you try to get html via `html()` function of variable you're not defined. Also, as I can see in your code, you want to add required class to label. If it is, you need to define this label in you `each` loop like this `var element = jQuery(this); var element = jQuery(this).attr('for');` . I can put working script to you, if you share your html.

Comment: @ OlegNurutdinov  ,I'm working on woocommerce site, HTML form generate by plugin and output,required field generate by them, In that form to one dropdown/field  I want to add custom mandatory mark .So I try to add mandatory to my dropdown/field using jquery while in form load.This is my HTML what I want add mandatory mark

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov  `<label for="billing_state" class="">City </label>
<select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" class="state_select  select2-hidden-accessible" autocomplete="address-level1" data-placeholder="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
 <option value="Rathukohodigala">Rathukohodigala</option><option value="Ratkarawwa">Ratkarawwa</option><option value="Ratmale">Ratmale</option>
 <option value="Ratmalwala">Ratmalwala</option>
 <option value="Thuraineelavanai">Thuraineelavanai</option>
</select>`